# VTK loop over pixels in image

Tags: python, data-visualization, vtk

Hello I am working on project to interpolate a 2D image. I know how to loop over the x,y points and apply my bilinear interpolation method, but I do not know how to access the pixel value at the x,y point in the image file. I have come across resources that create an image data object, but I haven't seen any specific examples of code that extracts the pixel data values.

```
import vtk
from vtk.util.misc import vtkGetDataRoot
VTK_DATA_ROOT = vtkGetDataRoot()

imagefile = "clouds.jpg" # to load from current directory

# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

useFactory = True

if useFactory==True:
    createReader = vtk.vtkImageReader2Factory()         #using factory to create reader
    reader = createReader.CreateImageReader2(imagefile) #create the reader
else:
    reader = vtk.vtkJPEGReader();

reader.SetFileName(imagefile)

# create an ImageActor. It has its own mapper included in the object
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

#RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOOP X,Y AND APPLY
#BILINEAR INTERPOLATION

# assign actor to the renderer
ren.AddActor(actor)

# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

The image is 256x256 so I was just going to apply my method in a double four loop and reconstruct the interpolated image, but I don't know how to get the value of the image at a set x,y coordinate. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with numpy_support:

```py
import vtk
from vtk.util.misc import vtkGetDataRoot
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy
VTK_DATA_ROOT = vtkGetDataRoot()

imagefile = "clouds.jpg" # to load from current directory

# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

useFactory = True

if useFactory==True:
    createReader = vtk.vtkImageReader2Factory()         #using factory to create reader
    reader = createReader.CreateImageReader2(imagefile) #create the reader
else:
    reader = vtk.vtkJPEGReader();

reader.SetFileName(imagefile)
reader.Update()
imgdata = reader.GetOutput()


# create an ImageActor. It has its own mapper included in the object
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

#RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOOP X,Y AND APPLY
#BILINEAR INTERPOLATION
print(vtk_to_numpy(imgdata.GetPointData().GetScalars()))

# assign actor to the renderer
ren.AddActor(actor)

# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```